# Excel : Sum of max in pivot table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot, pivot-table, powerquery

I would like to create a pivot table which displays the sum of a column depending on the time that person that can work on.

I have the following data in a sheet on Excel :

The workload is the time that a person expect working on a task in one week.
The column AV represent the days that a person is working in one week.

| KEY | Content Type | Week | Task | Name | Workload | AV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Week 01 : 09 oct - 13 oct * Person 1 | Departement A | Week 01 : 09 oct - 13 oct | Task 1 | Person 1 | 2 | 5 |
| Week 01 : 09 oct - 13 oct * Person 2 | Departement A | Week 01 : 09 oct - 13 oct | Task 1 | Person 2 | 2 | 4 |
| Week 01 : 09 oct - 13 oct * Person 3 | Departement A | Week 01 : 09 oct - 13 oct | Task 1 | Person 3 | 2 | 5 |
| Week 01 : 09 oct - 13 oct * Person 1 | Departement A | Week 01 : 09 oct - 13 oct | Task 2 | Person 1 | 2 | 5 |
| Week 01 : 09 oct - 13 oct * Person 2 | Departement A | Week 01 : 09 oct - 13 oct | Task 2 | Person 2 | 1 | 4 |
| Week 01 : 09 oct - 13 oct * Person 3 | Departement A | Week 01 : 09 oct - 13 oct | Task 2 | Person 3 | 0 | 5 |
| Week 01 : 09 oct - 13 oct * Person 1 | Departement A | Week 01 : 09 oct - 13 oct | Task 3 | Person 1 | 1 | 5 |
| Week 01 : 09 oct - 13 oct * Person 2 | Departement A | Week 01 : 09 oct - 13 oct | Task 3 | Person 2 | 0 | 4 |
| Week 01 : 09 oct - 13 oct * Person 3 | Departement A | Week 01 : 09 oct - 13 oct | Task 3 | Person 3 | 0 | 5 |

At the moment, this is the result that I get with a pivot table and the sum of availability (option : "sum of availability" in my pivot table.

|  |  |  |  | Workload | Availability |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Departement A |  |  |  | 8 | 28 |
|  | Week 01 : 09 oct - 13 oct |  |  | 8 | 28 |
|  |  | Person 1 |  | 5 | 15 |
|  |  |  | Task 1 | 2 | 5 |
|  |  |  | Task 2 | 2 | 5 |
|  |  |  | Task 3 | 1 | 5 |
|  |  | Person 2 |  | 3 | 8 |
|  |  |  | Task 1 | 2 | 4 |
|  |  |  | Task 2 | 1 | 4 |
|  |  | Person 3 |  | 2 | 5 |
|  |  |  | Task 1 | 2 | 5 |

The result that I expect is :

|  |  |  |  | Workload | Availability |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Departement A |  |  |  | 8 | 14 |
|  | Week 01 : 09 oct - 13 oct |  |  | 8 | 14 |
|  |  | Person 1 |  | 5 | 5 |
|  |  |  | Task 1 | 2 | 5 |
|  |  |  | Task 2 | 2 | 5 |
|  |  |  | Task 3 | 1 | 5 |
|  |  | Person 2 |  | 3 | 4 |
|  |  |  | Task 1 | 2 | 4 |
|  |  |  | Task 2 | 1 | 4 |
|  |  | Person 3 |  | 2 | 5 |
|  |  |  | Task 1 | 2 | 5 |

The difference between these two tables is that I have the sum of each person availability, in this example (5 + 4 + 5)

Is it a way to do it? If you need more informations, feel free to ask

Thank in advance,

Fapinski.

Comment: I think you could try sumifs().

Comment: This just looks like you need to add a calculated field of available - worked?

Comment: Is Availability the same per Name per Week?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that Availability is the same (or constant) per Name per week, then you can try the following:

1. Select your table and then `Add to Data Model` via `Power Pivot` tab in the ribbon. This should open up Power Pivot for Excel window with your table loaded in.
2. At the bottom-half, select any cell and create a Measure with:

```
Availability := 
  SUMX(
    SUMMARIZE('Table1', 'Table1'[Name], 'Table1'[Week], 'Table1'[AV]), 
    'Table1'[AV]
  )
```

[image]

3. Go back to the main Excel window, and now you can create a pivot based on the data model, using the new `Availability` measure.
   [image]

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the existence of power pivot in Excel ;)  The solution works!
However, I'm trying to make it possible with some java code. 
Is there a way to figure it out? If not, I'll approve the response :) 

Thanks.

Comment: Urm... not sure what you mean by "java code"; your question didn't mention anything on that. What is your overall scenario or use case?